# Trouble with MX for subdomain at Google Hosted

Tags: linux, dns, bind

I'm having trouble setting a MX record for a subdomain. The problem is that the subdomain is a CNAME and located at googlehosted. I was instructed that I needed to set up a MX for that subdomain to complete the mail set up on that site.

Setting IN MX for a CNAME, caused the zone to not load in bind.

I added the full subdomain name and included the MX, and it didn't complain..

```
$TTL    3600
@               IN SOA  ns1.myserver.com. support.myserver.com. (
                                2012013023 ; serial
                                3H     ; refresh (3 hours)
                                15M       ; retry (15 minutes)
                                1W    ; expire (1 weeks)
                                1D      ; minimum (1 day)
                                )
                IN NS           ns1.myserver.com.
                IN NS           ns2.myserver.com.
                IN A            xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
                IN MX           1 ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
                IN MX           5 ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
                IN MX           5 ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
                IN MX           10 ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
                IN MX           10 ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
www             IN A            xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
mail            IN CNAME        ghs.googlehosted.com.
calendar        IN CNAME        ghs.googlehosted.com.
docs            IN CNAME        ghs.googlehosted.com.
sites           IN CNAME        ghs.googlehosted.com.
asdfasdf.sites.myserver.com. IN CNAME gv-asdfasdf.dv.googlehosted.com.

sites   IN MX       1 ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
```

But when I run a nslookup on MX, it's not showing a MX value just the canonical?

```
nslookup
> set type=mx
> server ns1.myserver.com
Default server: ns1.myserver.com
Address: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx#53
> sites.myserver.com
Server:         ns1.myserver.com
Address:        xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx#53

sites.myserver canonical name = ghs.googlehosted.com
```

I need to set up a MX for sites.myserver.com to point to 
1 ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.

Answer (score 0):

That zone file is still invalid and bind should refuse to start. Out-of-zone data (asdfasdf.sites.myserver.com) is ignored but CNAME and other data for the same domain can not coexist.

[RFC2181](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2181), 10.1. CNAME resource records:

> ...
>
> An alias name (label of a CNAME record) may,    if DNSSEC is in
> use, have SIG, NXT, and KEY RRs, but may have no    other data.
>
> ...